# iPhone 4S does not get detected in Windows

Tags: iphone

When I connect my iPhone 4S to my computer, iTunes does not detect it. iPhone pops the message of USB connectivity and defaults to Mass Storage. Windows shows the message that "Device is ready to use" and I can read both drives of the iPhone in Windows Explorer. However iTunes does not detect the device and the "Devices" tab does not appear.

I've tried:

Restarting the phone.
Restarting the computer.
Connecting the phone to a different computer.
(I'm on version 4.3.3 (8J2), firmware 01.59.00 and iTunes 10.5.3.3)

Comment: can you tell if the iTunesHelper process exists within Task Manager?

Answer (score 1):

Verify that the iPod service is running by doing the following:

First, close iTunes and disconnect your iPhone from your computer. Then:

1. Go to Start
2. Go to Run
3. Type "services.msc" and hit <kbd>enter</kbd>.
4. Find the iPod Service
5. Right click on it and click Start or Restart Service
6. Reconnect your iPhone to your machine.

If this does not resolve the issue, try going through the steps in [this knowledgebase article](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS1363).